# Display Outlook using RDCOMClient in R

Tags: r, outlook

I want to use R to create an outlook email without sending the email (I want to preview the email / check numbers before sending).

```
library(RDCOMClient)
outlook<-COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = outlook$CreateItem(0)
```

How can I show the message window with the email?

Answer (score 0):

Call outMail.DIsplay(). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx.

Comment: I tried that but get: Error: could not find function "outMail.Display"

Comment: Did you specify the parameter (true)?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `RDCOMClient` library in R, the correct syntax for the VBA Display function replaces `.Display()` with `$Display()`.

```
outlook<-COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = outlook$CreateItem(0)
outMail$Display()
```